# FlutterPlugin error when I try to run the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

how are you? When I try to run the emulator on both Android Studio and Visual Studio Code, the following error message appears:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C: \ src \ flutter \ packages \ flutter_tools \ gradle \ flutter.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> FlutterPlugin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please, is anyone going through or has been through it and knows how to solve it?
Thank you!!

Comment: see if [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55619) can help you.